# Intellij gradle project: packages not found

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Intellij gradle project: packages not found. For example,

```
import com.example.Foo;
```

The project has multiple source sets:

```
main
foo
```

command-line build: no errors, but Intellij java editor complains.

Tried:

Refresh gradle projects, refresh dependencies, invalidate cache and restart

Is there a way to show the dependencies jars for a source set?

Comment: Dependencies are shown in "Project Structure | Modules | <Module> -Dependencies tab". Could you provide sample project example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: the dependencies tab: is for whole project, not for individual source sets. The dependencies jars are shown as red.

Comment: They are per module. Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: It is working now after cleaning everything, and re-import the project. thanks.